# Where do PHP echos go when you are posting to a page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, echo

This might be a dumb question. I'm fairly new to PHP. I am trying to get a look at some echo statements from a page I'm posting to but never actually going to. I can't go directly to the page's url because without the post info it will break. Is there any way to view what PHP echos in the developer console or anywhere else?

Here is the Ajax:

```
function uploadImage(image) {
  
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("image", image);

      imgurl = 'url';
      filepath = 'path';
      $.ajax({
        url: imgurl,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        success: function(url) {
          var image = $('<img class="comment_image">').attr('src', path + url);
          $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

And here is the php file:

```
<?php
  $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $uploaddir = 'path';
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($image);
  if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile)) {
    echo $uploadfile;
  } else {
    echo "Unable to Upload";
  }
?>
```

So this code runs fine but I'm not sure where the echos end up and how to view them, there is more info I want to print. Please help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "post to but never go to"? Your PHP code will never run if you don't send a request to that page, or another page that includes that code. And if you output something in your PHP script, it will be part of the response (the page contents, what you see in the browser window). If you post data to PHP, that data will only exist for that request. After that, it's gone. If you want to test POST data, you could simply create a simple HTML form with the correct inputs and post that to the page you want to see.

Comment: What I mean is I'm submitting a form to a PHP page that takes the data and writes it to a database. That's all it does. The url never changes. But there are echo statements in that PHP file, and I'm just wondering where if anywhere those print out.

Comment: Any echo will be part of the response for your Ajax request. If you show your Ajax request (the code), it will be easier for us to point out where/how you get get it. Basically, an "echo" just outputs data to the page, just like if it was hard coded (like any HTML you might have)

Comment: For future reference, add _all_ details in your question from the start. You said in your comment under the answer you got that you know how normal form submissions work, but nowhere in the question did you mention Ajax (which should have been the main focus for your question.) You should also always include the relevant code.

Comment: My bad for not writing a good question. I have updated it with the code, do you mind looking it over again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already handle the response from PHP (which contains all the outputs, like any `echo`)

In the below code you have, `url` will contain all the output.

To see what you get, just add a `console.log()`

```
$.ajax({ 
    ...
    success: function(url) {
        // Output the response to the console
        console.log(url);

        var image = $('<img class="comment_image">').attr('src', path + url);
        $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
    },
    ...
}
```

One issue with the above code is that if the upload fails, your code will try to add the string "Unable to upload" as the image source. It's better to return JSON with some more info. Something like this:

```
// Set the header to tell the client what kind of data the response contains
header('Content-type: application/json');

if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile)) {
    echo json_encode([
        'success' => true,
        'url'     => $uploadfile,
        // add any other params you need
    ]);
} else {
    echo json_encode([
        'success' => false,
        'url'     => null,
        // add any other params you need
    ]);
}
```

Then in your Ajax success callback, you can now check if it was successful or not:

```
$.ajax({ 
    ...
    dataType: 'json', // This will make jQuery parse the response properly
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success === true) {
            var image = $('<img class="comment_image">').attr('src', path + response.url);
            $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
        } else {
            alert('Ooops. The upload failed');
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

If you add more params to the array in your `json_encode()` in PHP, you simply access them with: `response.theParamName`.

Comment: Thank you for the good response sir

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example...

**HTML (Form)**

```
<form action="script.php" method="POST">
    <input name="foo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP Script (script.php)**

```
<?php

    if($_POST){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST); // See what was 'POST'ed to your script.
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
    }

    // The rest of your PHP script...
```

Another option (rather than using a HTML form) would be to use a tool like [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/) which can be useful for simulating all types of requests to pages (and APIs)

Comment: I know I can see the results if the window changes location to the new php page, but I'm using ajax to POST to the page without changing the url. Where would those echo statements show up then?

Comment: Well if I had known you were using ajax at the start I would have told you to open Developer Tools in your browser, go to the network tab (A) and submit the ajax request on your webpage. You should see the ajax request appearing in (A). Just click on the ajax request and go to the response tab and you will be any content you are returning (or echoing)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. My bad for not making the question better.